# CSS styling not appearing on PHP page

Tags: php, html

I want to display some styling for my webpage, but the styling I'm defining for it is not appearing.

I've tried looking over the code and nothing I edit seems to work.

(this is part of my functions.php page. echo is the code I am trying to style)

```
    function getPro() {

    global $con;

$get_pro = "select * from products order by RAND() LIMIT 0,6";

$run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $get_pro);

while($row_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro)) {

    $pro_id = $row_pro['product_id'];
    $pro_cat = $row_pro['product_cat'];
    $pro_brand = $row_pro['product_brand'];
    $pro_title = $row_pro['product_title'];
    $pro_price = $row_pro['product_price'];     
    $pro_image = $row_pro['product_image'];

echo "
        <div id='single_product'>

            <h3><b>$pro_title<b></h3>

            <img src='admin_area/product_images/$pro_image' width='180' height='180' />

            <p><b> $ $pro_price </b></p>

            <a href='details.php' style='float:left;'>Details</a>
            <a href='index.php'> <button style='float:right'>Add to Cart</button></a>


        </div>  ";
}
```

(this is the styling from my style.css page)

```
   #single_product {float:left; margin-left: 20px; padding:10px;}

   #single_product img {border:4px solid black;}
```

(this is part of my index page where functions is executed)

```
<div class="content_wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar"> 
    <div id="sidebar_title">Categories</div>

  <ul id="cats">
    <?php getCats(); ?>
  </ul>

 <div id="sidebar_title">Brands</div>
<!-- brands and categories have the same ul id -->
    <ul id="cats">
    <?php getBrands(); ?>
    </ul>
</div>

    <div id="content_area">

        <div id="products_box">

            <?php getPro(); ?>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

I want the styling for 'single_product' set the way it is defined on my css page.

Comment: where is the code that incorporates your stylesheet?

Comment: Are you sure the styling isn't getting applied but just doesn't appear how you expect? Like have you tried using a developer console on your browser to check if the styling is applied?

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you want to define css use class and give css like

```
echo "<div class='single_product'>
        <h3><b>$pro_title<b></h3>
        <img src='admin_area/product_images/$pro_image' width='180' height='180' />
        <p><b> $ $pro_price </b></p>
        <a href='details.php' style='float:left;'>Details</a>
        <a href='index.php'> <button style='float:right'>Add to Cart</button></a>
    </div>  ";
```

---CSS---

```
   .single_product {float:left; margin-left: 20px; padding:10px;}
   .single_product img {border:4px solid black;}
```

beacuse you are using while loop and css define in id thats why not working try to use class and define

Comment: I went back and changed some of the code and now the borders I wanted to appear are now appearing. However, the bolding of the <p> and <h3> tags I have in the function isn't appearing.